# How we can interact with the iphone scheduler through code?

Tags: iphone

is there any way via which we can interact to iphone scheduler and insert and delete data through any iphone application. And produce alerts on that particular time.A user will insert data in the scheduler through the iphone app and user will get notify on that particular time .

Thanks 
Balraj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, programmatic access to the calendar application and it's data is not supported. Neither is anything that resembles cron -- the only chance you have is to run your own server (or get one of the offerings online) and use the push notification system.  Alas, that's a very strange way to approach the timing problem you have and of course relies on the network for something that should be able to be done just on the device.  But Apple doesn't let us.

Comment: Maybe we should just all wait for iPhone OS 4.0 -- it's supposedly bringing in a load of good features.

Comment: The thought of some app accidentally nuking my calendar is not appealing.